# Devise Registerable + client_side_validations to validate edit_registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, client-side-validation

I'm trying to validate the presence of the current_password field in the Devise-generated form for editing user registrations.

**registrations/edit.html.erb**:

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :method => :put, :validate => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>

    <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
      <p>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></p>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.input :password, :autocomplete => "off", :hint => "leave it blank if you don't want to change it", :required => false %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => false %>
    <%= f.input :current_password, :hint => "we need your current password to confirm your changes", :required => true, :validate => true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

This does not seem to work.  Submissions with blank current_password fields go through and are validated on the server.  I'm not sure on where to look or what to do to have client_side_validations be able to deal with this.  I'm not exactly sure where the registration model is for that matter.

Poking around devise, I see that the validation of current_password is handled in a way that I doubt client_side_validations will ever pick up: [Relevant methods in Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/03f2a6a5e43edee28258c171b19ba4b70d174f5a/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L56) .  I feel like I may go with a simple blur event in jquery for this case.